# Styled Components rendering Styled tag based on props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, tsx

I am building an app and want to have Primary, Secondary and Tertiary buttons, I did not want to create 3 separate components which would be this same but with different Styled Component so I wanted to conditionally display the proper tag like in a code below, but I am getting an error JSX element type 'ButtonStyles' does not have any construct or call signatures. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const PrimaryStyles = styled.button`
  width: 26rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background-image: ${({ theme }) => theme.gradients.ry};
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.black};
  font-size: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 30px ${({ theme }) => theme.red + "70"};
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 1rem;
`;

const SecondaryStyles = styled.button``;

const TertiaryStyles = styled.button`
  border: none;
  background: none;
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.grey};
`;

interface IProps {
  type: "button" | "reset" | "submit";
  children: React.ReactNode;
  onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>;
  primary?: boolean;
  secondary?: boolean;
  tertiary?: boolean;
}
export const Button: React.FC<IProps> = ({
  children,
  onClick,
  type,
  primary = true,
  secondary,
  tertiary,
}) => {
  const ButtonStyles = primary
    ? PrimaryStyles
    : secondary
    ? SecondaryStyles
    : tertiary
    ? TertiaryStyles
    : null;
  return (
    <ButtonStyles type={type} onClick={onClick}>
      {children}
    </ButtonStyles>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of this logic:

```
const ButtonStyles = primary
    ? PrimaryStyles
    : secondary
    ? SecondaryStyles
    : tertiary
    ? TertiaryStyles
    : null;
```

If it's not `primary`, `secondary` or `tertiary` it will be `null`. So your code will setting `ButtonStyles` as `NULL` and then you cannot do this:

```js
 return (
    <ButtonStyles type={type} onClick={onClick}>
      {children}
    </ButtonStyles>
  );
```

A solution to this is remove the `NULL` option, something like:

```js
const ButtonStyles = primary
    ? PrimaryStyles
    : secondary
    ? SecondaryStyles
    : TertiaryStyles;
```

Another approach, to avoid the ternary conditional operator would be doing something like this:

1. Create an object containing the 3 styles options:

```js
interface IButtonStyles {
  [key: string]: StyledComponent<"button", any, {}, never>;
}

const buttonStyleTypes: IButtonStyles = {
  primary: PrimaryStyles,
  secondary: SecondaryStyles,
  tertiary: TertiaryStyles,
};
```

2. Change your IProps to something like that:

```js
interface IProps {
  type: "button" | "reset" | "submit";
  children: React.ReactNode;
  onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>;
  styleType?: string;
}
```

3. The Button component to this:

```js
const Button: React.FC<IProps> = ({
  children,
  type,
  styleType = "primary",
}) => {

  const ButtonStyles = buttonStyleTypes[styleType];

  return <ButtonStyles type={type}>{children}</ButtonStyles>;
};
```

4. And finally, you can create the button like this:

```js
<Button type={"button"}>primary</Button>
<Button type={"button"} styleType='secondary'>secondary</Button>
<Button type={"button"} styleType='tertiary'>tertiary</Button>
```